# until or unless

Tags: word-usage

I encountered a sentence:

> we should not read the next ______ we have learned the first one well.

(A) unless    (B) until

The answer is (B) until, but why unless is not right here? Is it okay to use unless?

Comment: Welcome to ell, jonathan. Both answers are grammatically correct, but **until** is probably the intended meaning.

Answer (score -1):

Don't use *unless.* The major difference between them is that *unless* is used for some *condition.* And, *until* or *till* for *some point of time/thing.*

Compare:

> *I will not talk to her **unless** she apologizes for her mistake* - a kind of condition

But,

> *We should not read the next **until** we have learned the first one well.* - a point of time of reading the first one.

Note that you can use *both* i.e. *until and unless* in certain conditions.

[Reference: BBC](http://www.bbc.co.uk/worldservice/learningenglish/grammar/learnit/learnitv338.shtml)

Comment: Using **unless** in the OP's question would be grammatically and semantically correct, but as you have pointed out the meaning would be different. **until** is probably the intended meaning, but **unless** is not wrong.

Comment: That's right! @JavaLatte Actually, a hairline difference for non-natives. I've seen many Indians using both to avoid confusion! :)

Comment: But _having learned the first one well_ could be regarded as a condition for going on to the next. (I agree that _until_ was probably intended.)